# django cms error in migrate - Found wrong number (0) of constraints

Tags: python, mysql, django, content-management-system

I installed application in AWS and made a new databse.

I ran python manage.py migrate

But below error's occurred.

I use mysql. I don't know what change things in schema.

Please, help me out.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
     'cms',
    'treebeard',
    'menus',
    'sekizai',
    'djangocms_admin_style',
    'fluent_dashboard',
    'admin_tools',
    'admin_tools.menu',
    'admin_tools.theming',
    'admin_tools.dashboard',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'rest_framework',
]
```

ValueError: Found wrong number (0) of constraints for cms_page(publisher_is_draft, application_namespace)

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: menus, cms, admin, menu, contenttypes, sessions, currency, auth, dashboard, sites
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying cms.0008_auto_20150121_0059...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/var/www/apps/currency_a1/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/var/www/apps/currency_a1/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/var/www/apps/currency_a1/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/var/www/apps/currency_a1/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/var/www/apps/currency_a1/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/var/www/apps/currency_a1/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 92, in migrate
    self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/var/www/apps/currency_a1/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 121, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/var/www/apps/currency_a1/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 198, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/var/www/apps/currency_a1/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 123, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/var/www/apps/currency_a1/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 359, in database_forwards
    getattr(new_model._meta, self.option_name, set()),
  File "/var/www/apps/currency_a1/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 318, in alter_unique_together
    self._delete_composed_index(model, fields, {'unique': True}, self.sql_delete_unique)
  File "/var/www/apps/currency_a1/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/schema.py", line 87, in _delete_composed_index
    return super(DatabaseSchemaEditor, self)._delete_composed_index(model, fields, *args)
  File "/var/www/apps/currency_a1/venv/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 347, in _delete_composed_index
    ", ".join(columns),
ValueError: Found wrong number (0) of constraints for cms_page(publisher_is_draft, application_namespace)
```

freeze

```
amqp==1.4.9
anyjson==0.3.3
APScheduler==3.1.0
beautifulsoup4==4.4.1
billiard==3.3.0.23
celery==3.1.23
configparser==3.5.0b2
dashboardmods==1.0
DateTime==4.1.1
dj-database-url==0.4.1
Django==1.9.6
django-admin-tools==0.7.2
django-celery==3.1.17
django-classy-tags==0.7.2
django-cms==3.3.0
django-cors-headers==1.1.0
django-filter==0.13.0
django-fluent-dashboard==0.6.1
django-formtools==1.0
django-markup==1.1
django-mptt==0.8.4
django-sekizai==0.9.0
django-staff-toolbar==1.0.1
django-treebeard==4.0.1
djangocms-admin-style==1.2.2
djangocms-installer==0.8.9
djangorestframework==3.3.3
djangorestframework-apidoc==0.0.1
feedparser==5.2.1
future==0.15.2
gunicorn==19.6.0
html5lib==0.9999999
kombu==3.0.35
Markdown==2.6.6
Menus==0.1.7
mysqlclient==1.3.7
pbr==1.9.1
publicsuffix==1.1.0
Pygments==2.1.3
pytz==2016.4
requests==2.10.0
setproctitle==1.1.10
six==1.10.0
South==1.0.2
SQLAlchemy==1.0.13
stevedore==1.13.0
tzlocal==1.2.2
Unidecode==0.4.19
url==0.2.0
uWSGI==2.0.13.1
virtualenv==15.0.1
virtualenv-clone==0.2.6
virtualenvwrapper==4.7.1
zope.interface==4.1.3
```

Comment: Don't post your requirements, post your database models.

Comment: It's new installed. I just did fresh setup for cms. This error occured in applying 0008_auto_20150121_0059.py . I don't know why ValueError: Found wrong number (0) of constraints for cms_page(publisher_is_draft, application_namespace) is happend.

Comment: There's no existing database to migrate.

Comment: I don't understand, you have a DB in AWS, then you have no existing database, which one is it ? Are you following a tutorial ?

Comment: I meant it's installed in new database without exsiting data. Actually I think it's solve this. I ran " python manage.py managa.py cms --run-syncdb". After doing this, next things of 0008_auto_20150121_0059.py would be created.

Answer (score 0):

I did like "python manage.py migrate --fake"

So far, it seems to be finished in migrations.

It seems --fake option is to pass old actions in modules so that new installation is not effected by old ones, just install new one.

But, in this case, schema is not created for cms. --fake option is not solution. Is there anyone who make it through?

Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: menu, menus, admin, currency, auth, dashboard, cms, contenttypes, sites, sessions

```
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying cms.0008_auto_20150121_0059... FAKED
  Applying cms.0009_merge... FAKED
  Applying cms.0010_migrate_use_structure... FAKED
  Applying cms.0011_auto_20150419_1006... FAKED
  Applying cms.0012_auto_20150607_2207... FAKED
  Applying cms.0013_urlconfrevision... FAKED
  Applying cms.0014_auto_20160404_1908... FAKED
  Applying cms.0015_auto_20160421_0000... FAKED
```

python manage.py migrate

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: dashboard, sessions, menus, currency, cms, auth, contenttypes, menu, admin, sites
Running migrations:
```

Finally, I ran " python manage.py managa.py cms --run-syncdb". 
After doing this, next things of 0008_auto_20150121_0059.py would be created.